# What image characteristics are best for training object detection models?

Tags: image, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm trying to create a model to detect a few objects in my custom photos. Before training my model, I'd like to know ***if*** and ***how*** I should modify my images to improve its accuracy.

I don't have access to the photos at the moment, however, I can provide an example of the characteristics of the images I'll be working with:

1. There's a white piece of paper (so white background), and on it are a bunch of insects.
2. There are a few different kinds of insects, and they look unique from eachother (different colors, shapes, sizes etc.).
3. The camera is pretty zoomed out, so each insect is probably ~ 40x40 pixels (so it's not really high definition).

I don't know much about machine learning, but I'd assume that because the insects will be captured in low quality, the model will mainly end up relying on the general shape and color to distinguish/identify the insects (e.g. long or circular spot on photo, etc.).

Therefore, I was wondering if I should do anything to to the photos to achieve higher accuracy (before I train it). For example, if I increase the contrast in my photos, would the insect's borders be more defined and thus make it easier for the model to detect/identify them? Or, should I convert the images to grayscale or stick with RGB? Are there any other factors that should be considered?

Comment: Probably you will use faster R-CNN or Mask R-CNN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an employ standard preprocessing strategy like

1. Normalization of the RGB values
2. Horizontal/Vertical flipping
3. Affine transformation

Comment: Hi Karan, thanks for your suggestions. Let me know if I am wrong, but wouldn't flipping and transforming my images be more useful for increasing image sample size? I'm more curious about what characteristics of the existing images I should modify, such as contrast, brightness, etc.

Comment: Yes, basically it's there to aid the training of the neural network. Also, you are 100% correct in this. You don't need to modify the images for deep neural networks. The DNNs learn the representations on their own, and for classical CV models. Please let us know your training strategies